# Hibernate and Oracle: Primary Key constraint violation

Tags: java, hibernate, primary-key

In my web application I have multiple scheduled services which work on same entities ( like article, customer...etc). If I run a single service at time I've no problem, but when I run two services I get an error because the primary key unique constraint is violated. 
As primary key I use a generated Long value:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Every service read data from a txt file, create its entities and every 20 entities execute a flush on hibernate session followed by a clear. Only at the end of the execution of the service the session is committed.

How can I solve?

Comment: I've already a sequence called HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE. I try to change my annotaions but I continue to get the same error.

Comment: I tried also to print the id assigned to every entity and them are all different, but the error persist! Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Oracle supports only sequences for generated keys. Add a sequence to your database:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ARTICLE_SEQ;
```

Change your annotations to:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="articleSequence")
@SequenceGenerator(name="articleSequence", sequenceName="ARTICLE_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
```

It's best to use a separate sequence for each table/type.

Answer (score 0):

Create sequence in DB and use it like `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_NAME")`.

Comment: I think `@SequenceGenerator` is also needed, and `generator` references name of that generator, not sequence name. Sequence name is in `@SequenceGenerator`.